# $T: V \to V$ is a linear map. If $\dim(\ker T \cap \text{Im}T)\neq0$, prove $\dim\ker T^2\geq2$

Tags: linear-algebra

$T: V \to V$ is a linear map. If $\dim(\ker T \cap \text{Im}T)\neq0$, prove $\dim\ker T^2\geq2$

so I can deduce $\dim\ker T\geq 1$ Because the intersection of the image and the kernel, is contained in the kernel.

And it is known that $\dim\ker T^2\geq \dim\ker T$

So $\dim\ker T^2\geq 1$. But I have no idea how to prove that it can't be $1$.

Comment: Take some non-zero element $v$ in the intersection. It’s in the image of $T$, so there is some nonzero $w$ such that $Tw=v$. What is $T^2 w$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $v \in\ker T \cap \text{im } T$ be such that  $v \neq 0$. Then there is some $u$ such that $Tu = v$.
Clearly $u, v \in \ker T^2$.

We wish to show that $u, v$ are linearly independent, i.e. $u \neq kv$
for any $k \in \mathbb{F}$.

If $u = kv$, then $Tu = T(kv) = k(Tv) = k(0) = 0$,
so $v = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Should  it say $v\in \text{ker}T\cap\text{im}T$ and not $v\in \text{dim}( \text{ker}T\cap\text{im}T)$?

Comment: Oh, so it should. Thanks.